# How to tell an applicant who accepted another job "congratulations, the door is still open"?

Tags: interviewing, job-search, job-offer

I work for a small engineering consultancy (as an engineer) and have recently taken on the role of being the point of contact for applicants. I recently offered a summer internship to a student with an impressive CV and appropriate skills. The student unfortunately received an offer from a firm in their home town so took their offer over ours to be closer to family. I noticed all the advice on here and other sites I frequent over advice to the applicant but not to the interviewer.

What is the best way to tell the candidate "thanks for being part of the application process, congratulations on your other job, the door is still open in the future, all the best in your career"? In a professional manner.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You might ask them if it's OK to follow-up in a year, and give them the option to call you before that if they realize the other job wasn't what they expected.

Something like:

> "Dear ____, thank you for being part of our application process and congratulations on your new position. Is it OK if we follow-up with you in about a year to stay in touch and see how your career is going? And please feel free to contact us at any point before then."

Comment: I like the professionalism. But does this sentence "Is it OK if we follow-up with you in about a year to stay in touch and see how your career is going" comes across a bit more desperate, which in my experience scares off good candidates. I think this is what Kilisi meant by not "coming off as disappointed". As a small consultancy my main goal is not to lose any professionalism.

Comment: Something like "Please consider us in future when looking for new opportunities"?

Comment: It's a summer internship.  6 months later, or whenever is a good time early in the next year's hiring cycle, would be a fine time.

Answer (score 3):

I think you put it pretty well, nice and short, not too personal, and definitely friendly and well meaning.

I would avoid being too verbose, or coming off as disappointed. Perhaps a bit more formal would be good.